# jQuery filter matching

Tags: jquery, regex, filtering

I have a script that is looking for a live click event, but I am wanting the click to not apply to certain `<a>` tags

Here is my code so far:

```
$('a:not(.btn-control)').filter(function(index) {
  return $(this).attr('href').match(/#|void/);
}).live("click", function() {
  var url;
  url = $(this).attr('href');
  url = url.replace(/^.*#/, '');
  $.history.load(url);
  return false;
});
```

**Issue**
I have site where I have a static player, upon the clicking of a link I am using the HTML5 history functionality to load the new content so that the page never refreshes... to avoid having to go throughout my whole site and add classes to all of the links that should contain this functionality onClick, I am simply trying to filter out those with a `#` or a `javascript:void(0)` in the `href`

**Question**
How do I filter out those links whose `href` contains a `javascript:void(0)` or a `#`?

**Working Code**

```
$('a:not(.btn-control)').live("click", function() {
  var self, url;
  self = $(this);
  url = self.attr('href');
  if (url.match(/#|void/) === null) {
    url = url.replace(/^.*#/, '');
    $.history.load(url);
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: So...what's wrong? What doesn't work? Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Sorry... better clarification is above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/) state that:

> DOM traversal methods are not supported for finding elements to send to .live(). Rather, the .live() method should always be called directly after a selector, as in the example above.

Instead, you should handle all `a` tags, but exit out if you don't need to handle it.

```
$('a:not(.btn-control)').live("click", function() {
  var self = $(this);

  if (!self.attr('href').match(/#|void/)) {
    return;
  };

  // else continue and do stuff

  var url = self.attr('href');
  url = url.replace(/^.*#/, '');
  $.history.load(url);

  return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up! I am still having issues with this though... I will clean up my question above

Comment: The issue I am having is that the page refresh still happens

Comment: @dennismonsewicz: Glad to hear you got it sorted :)